# How to skip rows while importing csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, rows, skip

How to skip the rows based on certain value in the first column of the dataset. For example: if the first column has some unwanted stuffs in the first few rows and i want skip those rows upto a trigger value. please help me for importing csv in python

Comment: pandas `read_csv` method has attribute `skiprows`, you can define a callable which will return True or False based on your condition, then pandas will skip it. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the argument `skip_rows`

Here is sample code below to start with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('users.csv', skiprows=<the row you want to skip>)
```

For a series of CSV files in the folder, you could use the `for` loop, read the CSV file and remove the `row` from the `df` containing the `string`.Lastly, concatenate it to the `df_overall`.

Example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, concat, read_csv

df_overall = DataFrame()
dir_path = 'Insert your directory path'
for file_name in glob.glob(dir_path+'*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', header=None)
    df = df[~df. < column_name > .str.contains("<your_string>")]
    df_overall = concat(df_overall, df)
```

Comment: in this code we can directly give the number directly up to how much i can skip, but the thing is i didn't know how much it is exactly. it differ for different file. I need to skip the row unit i find the value say "ball". I need a solution for this. This value ball will come in 31st row for some file and 53rd row for some file. Pls help me in this regard

Comment: why not read the CSV file into the dataframe and then remove the row containing a particular 'string' in the dataframe.

Comment: I am trying to run it in a loop to read all the files (894 csv files) in a folder and merge the files to make it as a single data frame

Comment: I have modified the answer as you require.